# PHP download file UTF-8 BOM issue

Tags: php, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have a script which forces a PNG download but the file is corrupted due to `UTF-8 BOM`
How to discard the extra bytes in PHP without checking every included PHP file (in PrestaShop)
I tried omitting the buffer, with no luck

```
ob_start();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="render_product_'.$id_product.'.png"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($cache));
ob_end_clean();
readfile($cache);
exit();
```

Comment: You should not be outputting a BOM, not for PNGs and not for regular HTML either. You should be fixing this by removing the BOM from where it's being output. I know this is not the solution you want, but it's the one you deserve… err, wait…

Comment: I can't control all the code as my code is only a module which is part of a larger spec (PrestaShop) with a lot of other modules coded by other devs. I wanted to find a programmatical solution if possible :)